# keyword query with nullable

Tags: search, search-results, keywordquery

trying to query on multiple contenttype where one content type contains field `XYClosed(Yes/No)` and the other one does not contain it. So I created a scope and start writing fixed query. Returned results for two CTs look like this (inside individual results)

```
1 : <XYClosed></XYClosed>
2 : <XYClosed>True</XYClosed>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is include results where:

- if the element is filled then take only if it is not equal to true -> `-XYClosed:True`
- if the element is empty than take it to the results -> `???`

Can you help me how to achieve the 2nd rule and also somehow to combine these rules with OR?

Thanks, Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understand what you're trying to achieve.   But I think you are trying to specifically write a  query for nullable.  So here goes...Trying adding a parameter of :

```
 XYClosed:""
```

This should retrieve where the values are not set.

Comment: This does not work.